# Mail able to send but not receive

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

I have found and tried several solutions to why Mail.app (I'm running Mavericks) has not been able to download emails for about 5 hours. I can send just fine, but when I go to my gmail account there are a number of new emails.

I didn't make any modifications to any program. I can take all accounts offline for a while, totally reboot the laptop, and so forth, but still all I can do is send.

Comment: Welcome, we a group of unpaid computer users will tray to help you, because we like to do that. So, what are the settings in your web gmail for IMAP folders?

Comment: In Mail check that the Incoming mail server says imap.gmail.com !

Comment: And you are running Mavericks 10.9.2?